# How to access data attributes of an anchor tag in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

**CASE 1:** Function called using 'onclick' attribute of anchor element

```
<a href='#' onclick='modifyCustomerDetails()' data-action='modifyCustAction' data-params='customerId=567'>Modify Customer</a>

function modifyCustomerDetails() {
    var srcEl = $(this); 
    console.log("ACTION::"+srcEl.data('action')) ;  
    console.log("PARAMS::"+srcEl.data('params')) ;          
}
```

The output in the browser console is:

undefined
undefined

**CASE 2:** Anchor element bind using jQuery

```
$('a').bind('click', function() {

  var srcEl = $(this); 
  console.log("ACTION::"+srcEl.data('action')) ;    
  console.log("PARAMS::"+srcEl.data('params')) ;    
})
```

The output in the browser console
modifyCustAction
customerId=567

I read that jQuery sets the scope of the callback function to the element which is the subject of the callback.

1. Why is data attributes not accessible/undefined in the case 1 &
   accessible only in case 2?
2. How to access anchor element's data attributes in case 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CASE 1:

```
<a href='#' onclick='modifyCustomerDetails(this)' data-action='modifyCustAction' data-params='customerId=567'>Modify Customer</a>

function modifyCustomerDetails(obj) {
    console.log("ACTION::"+$(obj).attr('data-action')) ;  
    console.log("PARAMS::"+$(obj).attr('data-params')) ;          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1** pass `this` inside function

```
<a href='#' onclick='modifyCustomerDetails(this)' 
data-action='modifyCustAction' data-params='customerId=567'>Modify Customer</a>

function modifyCustomerDetails(currObj) {
    var srcEl = $(currObj); 
    console.log("ACTION::"+srcEl.data('action')) ;  
    console.log("PARAMS::"+srcEl.data('params')) ;          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `id= "modify_customer"` to your anchor tag

and use this jquery code

```
<a href="#" onclick="modifyCustomerDetails()" 
data-action="modifyCustAction" 
data-params="customerId=567" 
id="modify_customer"> Modify Customer</a>

$(function(){ 
var a = $("#modify_customer").data('params')
alert(a)
});
```

it will give result `customerId=567`

Answer (score 0):

I am not understanding your question clearly but i think you want to this

```
$('a').click(function(){
var propty= $(this); 
var action =propty.attr("data-action");
});
```